# Weird Convnet Prediction outputs

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I'm encountering a  weird problem with my convnet built with the help of  Andrej Karpathy's course.
The training process has passed successfully and i got a validation accuracy of 99 % ..i tested it several time with a batch of images and i got good results ..
[see picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P3l8.png) [image]
But my problem occurs when i try to predict one single  digit ,
what i mean is when i pass a batch of images to the convnet the prediction will be accurate but if i pass to it a single image(containing one digit), prediction will be strangely wrong ! it seems to be always '9' i don't know why !
i have tried to reduce the batch of predition and i noticed that the prediction is getting wrong when the batch size is 3 or less...

For example for this image : [(see here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcCoN.jpg)[image]
predicting all the digits at once give this result:

```
 y=solver.predict(x.reshape(-1,1,28,28))
```

Output :

> [1 2 3 4 5 6 8 7 9 8 8 8 8 8 0 0 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7]

and this is the out put of the loss function :

```
In [2]: solver.model.loss(x.reshape(-1,1,28,28))


Out[2]: array([[ -3.05978141e-01,   2.25838572e+01,  -5.81781553e+00,
         -7.84227452e+00,  -2.46782551e+00,  -1.29618637e+00,
         -2.95035720e+00,  -2.26347248e+00,  -5.52651288e+00,
         -8.74067704e+00],

   [  2.18639209e+00,  -7.95115414e-01,   1.86981992e+01,
     -6.38840481e+00,  -7.44371465e+00,  -1.14834364e+01,
     -4.42105065e+00,  -2.51756685e+00,  -6.03314564e+00,
     -5.00079953e+00],
   [ -1.16809867e+01,  -3.90351457e+00,  -4.81452891e+00,
      1.72001078e+01,  -2.30417016e+00,   6.21031225e+00,
     -6.60536260e+00,  -3.35170447e+00,  -1.19414808e+01,
     -2.13268100e+00],
   [ -6.51288912e+00,  -1.27769600e-01,  -2.12484109e+00,
     -8.07526307e+00,   1.82578221e+01,  -8.02727136e+00,
     -3.95705307e+00,   1.50088109e+00,  -6.49268179e+00,
     -2.64582758e+00],
   [ -7.10982458e+00,  -1.23677393e+00,  -6.55376129e+00,
     -5.64977668e-01,  -1.66012764e+00,   1.39098500e+01,
     -1.82974320e+00,  -6.67535891e-02,  -6.25050582e+00,
      5.19481684e-01],
   [  1.97013317e+00,  -3.92168803e+00,  -2.50538345e+00,
     -4.53388791e+00,  -6.02692771e+00,   4.28872679e+00,
      9.32534533e+00,  -7.12121385e+00,  -1.27127814e+00,
      1.16859809e+00],
   [ -5.00874596e+00,  -8.22430042e+00,   2.82489907e+00,
      4.40183597e+00,  -1.18154837e+00,  -6.85617478e+00,
     -2.04355341e-02,  -3.68542346e+00,   8.40770795e+00,
     -3.89586477e+00],
   [ -3.76888300e+00,   4.36662753e+00,  -1.06721865e+00,
     -5.43658272e-01,  -5.73712938e+00,  -5.08607578e+00,
     -6.80629281e+00,   1.03611542e+01,  -6.12515023e+00,
     -2.67285495e+00],
   [ -5.45556785e+00,  -1.00982438e+01,  -1.86838461e+00,
     -6.25084617e+00,   2.61021988e+00,  -6.15225244e+00,
     -8.41166503e+00,  -4.13774685e+00,   7.20263813e-01,
      2.01130722e+01],
   [ -5.25623049e+00,  -6.90369741e+00,   3.26657435e+00,
      4.80984753e+00,  -7.93036997e+00,  -4.10551415e+00,
     -3.98611960e+00,  -5.98433243e+00,   1.67853904e+01,
     -6.04416010e+00],
   [ -3.73519354e+00,  -4.69000763e+00,   7.11005865e-01,
     -7.79817234e-01,   4.95981297e-01,  -2.20233790e+00,
     -2.32379619e+00,  -7.31904658e+00,   1.01815587e+01,
     -2.92697528e+00],
   [ -3.70550605e+00,  -6.27884772e+00,  -1.15562031e+00,
     -7.79128777e-01,  -4.54130713e+00,  -8.82680476e-01,
     -5.15643101e+00,  -6.08414457e+00,   1.61823980e+01,
     -3.31924674e+00],
   [ -3.21343014e+00,  -5.50310651e+00,  -6.46784579e+00,
     -4.71090597e-01,   2.30565155e+00,   1.71298558e+00,
     -3.80354454e+00,  -5.77908110e+00,   7.99886231e+00,
     -1.53263277e+00],
   [ -5.02752362e+00,  -6.41713821e+00,  -2.75882859e+00,
      2.02198061e+00,  -7.31649294e-01,  -4.09780260e+00,
     -2.87254341e+00,  -4.76868410e+00,   1.14782529e+01,
     -1.32010697e+00],
   [  6.58318513e+00,  -1.59361387e+00,  -4.07994824e+00,
     -5.69145251e+00,  -3.74416814e+00,   4.06304645e+00,
      6.06811801e+00,  -6.00753335e+00,  -3.02293776e+00,
     -3.07097095e+00],
   [  7.63995824e+00,  -4.60587221e+00,  -2.12479379e+00,
     -8.23367696e+00,  -2.25116385e+00,   5.15873864e+00,
      4.75356097e+00,  -5.97345978e+00,  -5.97171695e+00,
      2.29368218e+00],
   [  2.84535499e+00,  -2.04897197e+00,  -1.90798644e+00,
     -5.22885750e+00,  -7.08722417e-01,   1.73670140e+00,
      1.11489922e+01,  -7.04308564e+00,  -3.25250603e+00,
     -4.53417172e+00],
   [  2.03252275e+00,  -5.40529310e+00,  -3.53667596e+00,
     -1.73374097e+00,  -1.55853211e+00,   6.61614808e+00,
      1.03727007e+01,  -8.07445330e+00,  -3.62687170e+00,
     -7.68923877e+00],
   [  8.60866851e-01,  -2.61086735e+00,  -3.97864755e+00,
     -3.46964219e+00,  -1.53576350e+00,   4.34321103e-01,
      1.25051786e+01,  -6.28857105e+00,  -2.85388750e-02,
     -5.99032711e+00],
   [ -7.11119637e+00,   1.32192098e+00,  -2.85581429e-01,
     -4.09789623e+00,  -2.73542444e+00,  -5.05718720e+00,
     -5.84672064e+00,   1.10982186e+01,  -5.43396446e+00,
      1.38815026e+00],
   [ -4.45070011e+00,   6.63612661e+00,  -2.38272164e+00,
     -5.08418780e+00,  -4.23138974e+00,  -4.84060683e+00,
     -6.11011890e+00,   7.69417553e+00,  -4.36085869e+00,
      1.77336902e+00],
   [ -3.19741107e+00,   7.66654742e-01,   9.01185936e-01,
     -3.57527153e+00,  -5.35865469e+00,  -4.38987324e+00,
     -5.46174960e+00,   6.97829754e+00,  -2.74923129e+00,
      3.29389455e+00],
   [ -6.11877337e+00,   4.01989815e+00,  -9.16340782e-01,
     -1.81711754e+00,  -5.84678589e+00,  -4.57215096e+00,
     -5.60624601e+00,   1.10141198e+01,  -5.38853792e+00,
      2.88915005e-01],
   [ -5.12862280e+00,   3.51793625e+00,  -2.56816990e+00,
     -2.43665530e+00,  -2.69804915e+00,  -6.44862518e+00,
     -5.20372901e+00,   1.08616926e+01,  -6.62861963e+00,
      8.75721537e-02]])
```

And here the results when i start reducing the batch size (Prediction batch):

Notice that the loss(x[0])  (digit '1' ) is different from the first row of loss(X) (corresponding to this same digit '1' ) and that sould be exactly the same values !!

The loss of the the whole batch " loss(X) " is correct ... you can see that for the first row for example the max value correspond to column 1 thus the number predicted is '1' , and so on for the rest ..except some normal prediction errors. And that's not by chance because i have tried a lot of examples.

```
In [7]: y=solver.predict(x[0:8].reshape(-1,1,28,28))
[1 2 3 4 5 6 8 7]

In [8]: y=solver.predict(x[0:4].reshape(-1,1,28,28))
[1 2 3 4]

In [9]: y=solver.predict(x[0:3].reshape(-1,1,28,28))
[1 2 5]

In [10]: y=solver.predict(x[0:2].reshape(-1,1,28,28))
[5 2]

In [11]: y=solver.predict(x[0:1].reshape(-1,1,28,28))
[9]

In [12]: solver.model.loss(x[0:1].reshape(-1,1,28,28))
Out[12]:
array([[-0.18494676, -0.09562021, -0.0050496 , -0.09319004, -0.01837853,
        -0.14772171, -0.11772445, -0.1030173 , -0.00983804,  0.00842318]])
```

Main program :

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from segm import segment
from cs231n.classifiers.fc_net import *
from cs231n.classifiers.cnn import *
from cs231n.data_utils import get_data
from cs231n.solver1 import Solver
from cs231n.fast_layers import *

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 10) # set default size of plots
plt.rcParams['image.interpolation'] = 'nearest'
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'

model = ConvNet(input_dim=(1, 28, 28),weight_scale=1e-2,reg=0)

solver = Solver()

#load saved trained convnet
solver.load_model('best1906.pkl')

#extract digits from loaded images    
lstChar = segment() 

x = np.asarray(lstChar)
# x need to to be processed here before making the forwardpass : 
y = solver.predict(x.reshape(-1,1,28,28))
```

You can find the program here : github. com/cthorey/CS231/tree/master/assignment2/

Not exactly the same , i added the module "segment" to extract digits from images ,and also the prediction and load_model functions .

I hope that my explanation is clear enough .

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What does each training image contain? One digit? Or many?

Comment: No,  one single digit,  each image represent the extracted digit.. i see that my explanation is bad.. sorry

Comment: Is this tensor flow? I'm not acquainted with it.

Comment: No,  manually implemented with numpy..  sth like that : https://github.com/cthorey/CS231

Comment: If you keep passing `x[0:...]` to the predict function, why are the outputs changing for the same images passed??

Comment: That's exactly what astonished me...   

Comment: Either your network didn't learn and is predicting junk, or you are magically shuffling it... Please post your code _here_. You would've made changes.

Comment: i tried a lot of examples... how could it predict several digits at once correctly ( except some errors) and not predict anything at all if input is one single digit. it is the same code as here:  https://github.com/cthorey/CS231
the loss function is the same as mine here ( see assignment 2/ Folder cs231/Classifier/convnet )

Comment: there's sth wrong somewhere for sure.. but you should know that the convnet is a series of heavy matrix multiplication (here i have 2 convlayer and 2 fully connected layers with batchnormalisation)  if sth is wrong in the main functions trainting process couldn't have started at all ...
I'm telling you that i'm quite sure that it's well trained and gives good results.. 
this is like searching in the sea :(

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you think is buggy? Maybe we can figure it out.

Comment: I found the origin of the problem..  it's all about messy implementation of the batchnormalisation layer ( the train mode and test mode were not really separated) ..  but i don't found the solution till now,  the mnist database is centred and normalized... everything is ok with mnist test examples .. i could predict them correctly .. but i don't know what to do with a new extracted digit before prediction..  how to prepare it !! it should be centred and normalized like the other but how !! it's one single digit

Comment: the problem is not about code anymore.. Read my previous comment.. the problem now how to make new extracted digit looks like MNIST database examples. How to preprocess them!

Comment: Okay. I think I know what the problem is. Give me a little time, and I'll explain.

Comment: Just tell me one thing. Where do you invoke the program from?

Comment: Anyway..  thank you very much coldspeed for your help...  Respect..  i will delete this question cos it's not valuable at all..  Thanks again

Comment: Ahh ookk one minute

Comment: Nah, it's not useless. It'll help future readers who come across this sort of thing.

Comment: Okk :)  i have just added the main program there.
You can check it out and take your time.

Comment: OP, sorry.... but can you paste `segment` too? :)

Comment: it's 160 line module !! i told you .. the problem is not about a bad code .. this is about the method of preprocessing data ...  segment function just return a list of the extracted digits from a given image.

Comment: Okay, so what I'm trying to figure out is this: 1) what does the data from the MNIST set look like in a numpy array 2) what is the default code doing to preprocess it 3) What are you doing to preprocess it... So I'm not able to follow something here. Where are you getting the testing images from? Is it from the same dataset used to train? Or somewhere else?

Comment: I'm asking because I once had a similar problem like this. In that case the issue was resolved by converting the images into boolean arrays. (Seriously)

Comment: i'm not preprocessing it at all .. segment return [0-255] arrays of  np.int8 images .. MNIST images are [0-1] arrays ( The digits have been size-normalized and centered in a fixed-size image) 
That's what i'm trying to do .. make them similars.

Comment: OP, let me know how it goes. I've posted my answer.

Comment: No @Coldspeed that did not work :/ 
i have figured out maybe another cause of that problem .
The training set are not only in [0,1] but they are a grayscaled .. there is float pixel values between [0,1].
and also they are mean substracted : 
mean_image = np.mean(X_train, axis=0)
        X_train -= mean_image
        X_val -= mean_image
        X_test -= mean_image
But mine are totally black and white. 0 or 255 values.
i have tried to rescaled my image to be in [0,1] and substracted the same mean as above.
x=(x / 255) - mean
 but without result till now.

Comment: So after doing that, the prediction was still bad? Hmm... you'll probably have to use some image library like PIL to replicate the preprocessing.

Comment: Yes still bad .. please reRead my comment i have just edited it.
Sould i maybe make them grayscaled like the training set .. blurring them a litte bit maybe ??

Comment: One more thing... your images and the originals are both one channel or RGB?

Comment: No non one channel .. grayscaled image are always one channel.

Comment: the main difference now between my image and training images is that they are grayscaled ... the image looks  blurred . but mine are only 0 and 1.

Comment: That makes no sense... can you remove the preprocessing code that is being done for the training images?

Comment: the Mean substraction ? then i have to retrain the network. okk i will do that later.
so you are  telling me that grayscaled or not does not affect the prediction a lot ?

Comment: No, grayscale images are fine. The test and train need to be the exact same. The network will learn how to predict on its own.

Comment: Ah ! Sorry You have not got my point . My extracted images are not really grayscaled ..they have not gray colors  i mean ! only pure black and white. 
0 or 255  only . but training and test sets of the MNIST are .. (grayscaled between 0 and 1 ) 
So either i shoud make  mnist boolean and retrain or mine grayscaled ..
right ??

Comment: KwFx, I don't see how you can grayscale your images. It just seems impossible. Your images have lost information content by effectively being binarised to these two values. So your only other option is to convert the grayscale (between 0 and 1) to explicitly 0 and 1.

Comment: i applied a 3x3 mean filter to the binary image , i get a grayscale image too similar to the others . but as usual wrong prediction !! 
There may be another cause somewhere !! i'm lost -_- -_-
I will try the other option (binarising the training set) .

Comment: i finally found the solution -_- it was a missed sqrt operation .
In test mode of batchnormalisation layer ,we should divide by running standard deviation but all that time i was dividing by running variance -_-
Thank you @Coldspeed .. i appreciate your help a lot ^_^

Comment: Congrats... Write an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okk..  i figured it out. It was a bad implementation of the batchnormalisation layer. So whoever encounters this kind of problem must make sure that train mode and test mode of batchnorm layer are well conceived  :

- keep track of  the running mean and running variance while training .
- At test mode calculate the output like this :

out = (x - running_mean)  / sqrt(running_var + epsilon)